# "Millennium" or "a thousand years"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Should I use "a millennium" or "a thousand years"? Here is my context:

> Another consequence of PET plastic is that it can take about **a millennium** to biodegrade.

Or

> Another consequence of PET plastic is that it can take about **a thousand years** to biodegrade.

This is in a formal essay.

Comment: You've spelled a thousand anus not a thousand annus.

Comment: @tchrist And who wants a thousand crones?

Comment: @AndrewLeach the OP says they're needed for PET to biodegrade

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They both mean exactly the same thing, so there is no reason other than style to prefer one over the other.

- 'Millennium' is less well known than 'thousand years' and therefore less understandable. Some people might understand 'millennium' to be just 'a long period of time'.
- 'Millennium' would probably be understood as less precise than 'thousand years'
- Millennium is more dramatic

It's really personal preference.

Comment: Anus and annus are different.

Comment: A good reason not to us _millennium_ is how easily it's misspelled.

Comment: Hey, @Mari-LouA, gimme a break! I'm thumb-typing on an iPad mini! :)

Comment: _"They both mean exactly the same thing, so there is no reason other than style to prefer one over the other."_ This is categorically incorrect. I'm surprised to see no one has called this out or asked for citations.

Comment: @TusharRaj millennium has religious and other connotations not shared with "a thousand years". Reference: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/millennium . And, am I wrong that "about a millennium" would sound weird or ironic, definitely not neutral?

Comment: @lebatsnok I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Although millennium means thousand years, it is often taken to mean that exact period between consecutive dates ending with '000'.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. However useful your answer may be, it needs authoritative sources cited to be taken seriously. Standard reference works should be cited.

Comment: +1. Add Oxford's definition to your post: A period of a thousand years, **especially when calculated from the traditional date of the birth of Christ.** (i.e. consecutive dates ending with '000')